# Using calc library with foreach loop over some coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am drawing a schematic diagram which contains the sun in several places. For the purpose of this example, the sun is just a circle surrounded by 12 equally spaced `a`'s.

Using the `calc` library

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \sunrad {1};
  \foreach \cen in {(0,0),(4,0),(8,3)}%
    {%
      \draw \cen circle (\sunrad);
      \foreach \k in {0,...,11}
        \draw ($ \cen + ({360*\k/12}:{1.2*\sunrad}) $) node{a};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

returns the error `Paragraph ended before \tikz@cc@parse@factor was complete.`

However if instead I use

```
\draw[shift={\cen}] ({360*\k/12}:{1.2*\sunrad}) node{a};
```

then I get the desired result with no error.

Why doesn't the `($`...`$)` construction work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly, but I guess that `calc` is looking for a `(` to start parsing coordinates, and it doesn't expand `\cen` immediately, and so fails. 
Changing the loop to `\foreach \cen in {{0,0},{4,0},{8,3}}`, and using `(\cen)` instead of `\cen` works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \sunrad {1};
  \foreach \cen in {{0,0},{4,0},{8,3}}%
    {%
      \draw (\cen) circle (\sunrad);
      \foreach \k in {0,...,11} 
        \draw ($ (\cen) + ({360*\k/12}:{1.2*\sunrad}) $) node{a};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a similar fix if I am using `\cen in {(A),(B),(C)}` where `(A)`, `(B)`, `(C)` have been defined previously?

Comment: @lastresort So `A`, `B`, `C` are `coordinate`s? Same exact fix: `\foreach \cen in {A,B,C}` and `(\cen)`.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I'm after.